# Do I Need to Prefix Variables Inside Functions?

Tags: functions, variables

Sorry, this is a noob question. But, I want to follow the best practices.

I read that functions and global variables should be prefixed in plugins.

So, for example,  `myfunction()`, should be `lax_myplugin_myfunction()`. And a variable, such as `$myvar`, should be `$lax_myplugin_myvar`.

Do I need to prefix a variable if it's in a function? For example,

```
lax_myplugin_myfunction() {

$count = 50;

return $count;

}
```

Should I prefix `$count` and make it `$lax_myplugin_count`? Or I don't have to bother with it as it's in a function. What's the best practice?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functions - yes.

Class methods - no (but prefix the class name).

Variables - inside your functions/methods - no (like in your example); inside template files - yes, because there are lots of global variables exposed by WP in them, and you might get conflicts...

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer One Trick Pony. Awesome!

Comment: In addition to @One Trick Pony's great answer here is a link you may find useful: http://codex.wordpress.org/User:CharlesClarkson/Global_Variables